# Differenciate between values in a dynamic picklist inside iteration

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

There are multiple picklist equivalent to the size of list .When I select 'A' as picklist value in one picklist, all the values in the  below / above picklist is updated with 'A'. I want  to set the value of each picklist independently

```
    <aura:iteration aura:id="fid" items="{!v.files}" var="obj"  indexVar="index">
      <tr > 
    <td><div class="slds-truncate"  data-value="{!index}">
                               <select data-selected-Index="{!index}"  aura:id="selectCreditor" name="selectCreditor"  value="{!v.selectedcred}" onchange="{!c.handleCreditorSelection}"  disabled="{!v.isDisabled}" >
                                    <option value=" ">None</option>
                                    <aura:iteration aura:id="credx" items="{!v.credname}" var="objname"  indexVar="idx">
                                            <option aura:id="opx" data-value="{!idx}" value="{!objname.Id}" label="{!objname.Creditor__r.Name}"></option>
                                    </aura:iteration>    
                                </select></div></td>
</td>
                    </tr>
                </aura:iteration>
```

Here's the client side controller

```
handleCreditorSelection: function(component,event,helper){

            var target; 
         if(event.getSource){
             target = event.getSource();  
             txtVal = target.get("v.value") ;
            component.set("v.selectedcred",txtVal);   
        }else{
             target = event.target;  
            var dataEle = target.getAttribute("data-selected-Index"); 
            console.log("Component at index "+dataEle+" has value "+target.value);
          
           component.set("v.selectedcred",target.value); 
       }
        
                                                 
            console.log("$$$ Creditor selected is ",component.get("v.selectedcred"));
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the markup you're setting `v.selectedcred` to the `value` attribute of every `select` in the iteration, so when you update one's value you're updating them all to the same value. It's unclear to me what you're trying to do, since when you select an option within a select, that option's `value` becomes the select's `value`.